# Difference between Reply x Answer x Response

Tags: grammar, synonyms, sentence, questions, conversation

I have a question about conversation in english... i'm only a recently student of english, then I've got a lot of question.

If I understood, in a conversation face to face or in some social media, when we ask for something, basically there are 3 ways to be answered:

- an answer:
- a response
- a reply

which one applies in a conversation and why? abd what is the difference between them?

Comment: On the present site there a prerequisite for all questions: you must first do some research, and only if this first step has not been fruitful you can say so as you  ask your question; if there is some result from your research but that you are not satisfied you can still ask your question; however, you must quote your research and explain what still remains unclear. For your present question, in particular, you must first do some research in various dictionaries, study the definitions and compare them.

Comment: Also, ell.stackexchange.com is dedicated to those _learning_ English

Comment: Any of them are acceptable, and there's very little difference.